# ¿De dónde proviene y desde cuándo se comenzó a usar 'móvil' con la acepción de 'motivo'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia

Pensaba que era una palabra reciente, pero no.

> Los celos fueron el **móvil** que desencadenó el crimen. Nieva habría descubierto que su esposa le era infiel con

> No se había identificado ningún **móvil del tiroteo**.

> Otro posible **móvil del crimen** está relacionado con la tendencia política.

> En el **móvil del crimen** de Asunta reside, diez meses después del asesinato, una de las grandes incógnitas de este mediático caso.

Busqué en el **CREA** filtrando por **derecho** y al parecer no se circunscribe solo a crímenes y tiroteos. Pero no aparece en ninguna de las definiciones en https://dle.rae.es/m%C3%B3vil, lo más cercano aunque insuficiente es la opción 3.

> 3. m. Aquello que mueve material o moralmente algo.

> 1    ica en su iniciación, avanza rápidamente hacia el **móvil económico**, típico de la delincuencia común, que **  1984            Medina, José Ramón                       Doctrina y testimonio                                        VENEZUELA       03.Derecho                     Dirección de Cultura, Universidad Central de Venezuela (Caracas), 1984

> 2    os debe existir la capacidad, la oportunidad y el **móvil delictivo**.  Así podríamos resumir, para remozar **  1984            Medina, José Ramón                       Doctrina y testimonio                                        VENEZUELA       03.Derecho                     Dirección de Cultura, Universidad Central de Venezuela (Caracas), 1984

> 3    saber si los actos de terrorismo que respondan a un **móvil político**, cometidos contra las autoridades dire **  1991            López Garrido, Diego

Busqué en el **CREA** filtrando por **noticias** y no aparece relacionado sólo con el crimen.

> 3    periódico que por la condición de las víctimas y el **móvil político** del asesinato, éste debería haber sido **  ---             ORAL                                     Informativo de Radio Nacional, noticias de las ocho, 17/03/9 ESPAÑA          09.Noticias                    ---

Busqué en el **CREA** filtrando por **protección civil** y no es sólo relacionado con el crimen.

> 8     narcotráfico en lugar de la guerrilla, ya que el **móvil** habría sido exclusivamente el obtener las Cessn **  1997            PRENSA                                   El Universal, 21/01/1997 : Dos venezolanos detenidos         VENEZUELA       03.Protección civil            Electronic Publishing Group (Caracas), 1997

> 10   , de modo que los investigadores sospechan que el **móvil del asesinato** fue el robo. En base a distintos  **  1997            PRENSA                                   La Nueva Provincia, 15/09/1997 : Profesor asesinado          ARGENTINA       03.Protección civil             (Bahía Blanca), 1997

> 11   reunidos hasta ahora continúan apuntando a que el **móvil del triple crimen** fue el robo. Aunque los inspe **  1988            PRENSA                                   El País, 02/02/1988 : Optimismo en las investigaciones del c ESPAÑA          03.Protección civil            Diario El País, S.A. (Madrid), 1988

> 12   n uno de los atracadores, que afirmó que el único **móvil del asalto** era conseguir una dosis de heroína p **  1987            PRENSA                                   El País, 01/04/1987 : Los asaltantes se rindieron tras larga ESPAÑA          03.Protección civil            Diario El País, S.A. (Madrid), 1987

> 13   por inspectores de la comisaría de Centro. El **móvil del crimen** se desconoce, según la información p **  1986            PRENSA                                   El País, 02/08/1986 : Muere un hombre apuñalado por varios d ESPAÑA          03.Protección civil            Diario El País, S.A. (Madrid), 1986

> 14   etención del autor del crimen ni sobre el posible **móvil** del mismo. La gestoría de la víctima se dedica  **  1984            PRENSA                                   El País, 01/08/1984 : ARAGÓN                                 ESPAÑA          03.Protección civil            Diario El País, S.A. (Madrid), 1984

> 15   La policía no ha podido averiguar el **móvil** que desencadenó la disputa. Al parecer, Vázquez **  1980            PRENSA                                   El País, 11/10/1980 : Su víctima recibió varios balazos      ESPAÑA          03.Protección civil            Diario El País, S.A. (Madrid), 1980

> 22   señaló que aunque el aprehendido ha señalado que el **móvil del homicidio** fue el robo de la camioneta Bronc **  1996            PRENSA                                   El Nacional, 12/09/1996 : Continuarán cambios: Seis jefes de VENEZUELA       03.Protección civil             (Caracas), 1996

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B3vil_(derecho)

> mobilis, adversarius, invidus - etiam potentiae in crimen vocabantur
> mobilis, mobile, mobilior -or -us, mobilissimus -a -ummovable; mobile; quick, active; changeable, shifting; fickle, easily swayed
> adversarius, adversaria, adversariumopposed, hostile, inimical, adverse; harmful, injurious, prejudicial
> invidus, invida, invidumhateful, ill disposed, hostile, malevolent; envious, jealous, grudging
> potentia, potentiae Fforce, power, political power
> crimen, criminis Nindictment/charge/accusation; blame/reproach/slander; verdict/judgment
> voco, vocare, vocavi, vocatuscall, summon; name; call upon

> Móvil: Finalidad o propósito que en cada caso existe para que una persona realice un acto.

¿Cuál es la etimología de móvil y desde cuándo se comenzó a usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La palabra *móvil*, antiguamente *mobil*, proviene del latín *mobĭlis*, "movible", "que se puede mover". Corominas afirma en su diccionario etimológico que se puede encontrar en textos desde 1499. El diccionario de Autoridades recoge este significado y además comenta que también existe la expresión *primer móbil*, que hace alusión a la esfera más alta del firmamento y hace que toda la bóveda celeste rote cada 24 horas. Dado que esta esfera sería el motor de todo lo que hay bajo ella, por alusión se considera *primer móbil* a la causa de la ejecución y logro de alguna cosa.

Cita el *Autoridades* el siguiente poema de Eugenio Coloma (1649-1697):

> *Unica razón del riesgo,
>
> que padezco y solicito,
>
> primer móbil del afecto,
>
> de mi mal último alivia.*

Por la misma época que el *Autoridades* se usaba ya de forma similar a la actual:

> *Este debe suponerse que es el origen y el primer móvil del mal gobierno que experimentan los reinos del Perú [...]*.
>
> Jorge Juan, *Noticias secretas de América*, 1747 (Perú).

Un ejemplo anterior

> *[...] o por tumba, o por cuna,
>
> que primer móvil fue de su fortuna.*
>
> Conde de Villamediana (Juan de Tassis y Peralta), *Poesías*, 1599-1622 (España).

Antes de esa fecha, ya en el siglo XVI y hacia atrás los ejemplos que veo de *primer móvil* hacen todos referencia a la bóveda celeste.